# Regular expression to make non-greedy

Tags: python, regex

I have a text like this

```
EXPRESS      blood| muscle| testis| normal| tumor| fetus| adult
RESTR_EXPR   soft tissue/muscle tissue tumor
```

Right now I want to only extract the last item in EXPRESS line, which is `adult`.

My pattern is:

```
[|](.*?)\n
```

The code goes greedy to `muscle| testis| normal| tumor| fetus| adult`. Can I know if there is any way to solve this issue?

Comment: How about just splitting at `|`?

Comment: `[^|]*\n` should give you a greedy match for everything until the end of the line that does not contain the character `|`, which should produce the result you want. So instead of trying to split on `|`, just take everything after the last occurrence (the last text between the last `|` and the newline)

Comment: Your pattern really means "as little as possible from (the _first_ occurrence of) `|` through `\n`".

Comment: Another idea is to let *greedy* `.*` consume everything before the *last* `|` and [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) anything after it: [`.*\| *(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/iAZhFC/2) [Python demo](https://tio.run/##LY67DsIwDEX3foWVKSkoCDEzdkctA0OlqtCUVspLjjNUyr@HQPF2LZ9z7TdanL3kvBrvkABVVZltCIRwBc6ax61tug5@89TOTQlMDC@tEpAKtIYE1qEZdcnROEwwK4plO05RU28LfW@Hr6YIgpsJChOiOu2Wf9pZJkp3qUUlgxrxtXBksu4T1FweBDvC/li58rha4ka@0UXPz0Lk/AE)

Answer (score 1):

You can take the capture group value exclude matching pipe chars after matching a pipe char followed by optional spaces.

If there has to be a newline at the end of the string:

```
\|[^\S\n]*([^|\n]*)\n
```

**Explanation**

- `\|` Match `|`
- `[^\S\n]*` Match optional whitespace chars without newlines
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^|\n]*` Match optional chars except for `|` or a newline
- `)` Close group 1
- `\n` Match a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WN8u0w/1)

Or asserting the end of the string:

```
\|[^\S\n]*([^|\n]*)$
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was answered quickly and the explanation is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this one. It spares you the space before, handle the \r\n case and is non-greedy:

```
\|\s*([^\|])*?\r?\n
```

[Tested here](https://regex101.com/r/f5mxEY/1)